# Processing code for image decoder returns þ

Tags: processing, decoder

I'm trying to make a decoder for images in processing, but it returns þ no matter what I put in. Help would be much appreciated.

```java
void setup() {
  //size(255, 255);
  colorMode(HSB);
  String result = decode();
  println(result);
  saveStrings("output.txt", new String[]{result});
}
String decode() {
  PImage img = loadImage("code.png");
  //image(img, 0, 0);
  img.loadPixels();
  String decoded = "";
  int[] chars = new int[255 * 255];
  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
      color col = img.pixels[i * 255 + j];//get(i, j);
      if (hue(col) == 0 && saturation(col) == 0) {
        chars[floor(hue(col) * 255 + saturation(col))] = j;
        println((char) j);
      }
    }
  }
  decoded = new String(chars, 0, chars.length);
  String[] list = decoded.split("\u0000");
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (String string : list) {
    builder.append(string);
  }

  decoded = builder.toString();
  return decoded;
}
```

Comment: Please [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Which line of code behaves differently from what you expected?

Comment: I think it's `chars[floor(hue(col) * 255 + saturation(col))] = j;`

Comment: Sounds like a good start. What is the value of every variable on that line? Break that line down into smaller individual steps so you can understand exactly what it's doing. What do you expect that line of code to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: It's supposed to order the character that the x value of the pixel corresponds to by the hue and saturation. It just returns þ no matter what I put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is likely at `if (hue(col) == 0 && saturation(col) == 0) {` 
The next line will **always** have 0 for `hue(col)` and `saturation(col)`. This means you are always executing `chars[0] = j;`, and your final result has only one character (the þ you described).

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.